# iOS app using Google Maps SDK for iOS crashes with Exception Code: 0x0000000000000000

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios, crash

The app am developing crashes on launch. The code runs perfectly on the simulator. However, when I run the .ipa archive through iTunes, the app crashes. As you can see from the error log below, NSObject call the `doesNotRecognizeSelector:` method. The culprit as pointed to by the line number displayed in the error log at Line 202 is:

```
self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;
```

in the `viewDidLoad:` method.

I commented this out but the error log simply caught the next line starting with:

```
self.mapView
```

Do note that `self.mapView` is an outlet of a `GMSMapView` configured through the storyboard.

The error log as follows:

```
Incident Identifier: 4F7341AD-7C0E-4383-8B40-AED516F165F0
CrashReporter Key:   6e031db1ca4c291576f3a897221102f0aef6019c
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:             MyAppName [3224]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/BFF8291E-CB8E-47F3-A43C-32F272C7DEA6/MyAppName.app/MyAppName
Identifier:          com.vikrambahl.MyAppName
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-07-08 15:33:28.745 +0800
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2d876ec6 __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38011ce2 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2d87a7f2 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 198
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2d8790f2 ___forwarding___ + 702
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2d7c8054 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
5   MyAppName                       0x000208bc -[MainViewController viewDidLoad] (MainViewController.m:202)
6   UIKit                           0x300aca2e -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 514
7   UIKit                           0x301572e8 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 28
8   UIKit                           0x301571fe -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 226
9   UIKit                           0x301567dc -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 76
10  UIKit                           0x30156504 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 568
11  UIKit                           0x30156274 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 40
12  UIKit                           0x3015620c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 180
13  UIKit                           0x300a82e0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 376
14  QuartzCore                      0x2fd24316 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 138
15  QuartzCore                      0x2fd1fb3a CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 346
16  QuartzCore                      0x2fd4eb48 -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 136
17  UIKit                           0x3012487a -[UIViewController window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 238
18  UIKit                           0x30122e84 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 3508
19  UIKit                           0x301220c2 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 42
20  UIKit                           0x3012204a -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 90
21  UIKit                           0x30121fe2 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 38
22  UIKit                           0x3011a65c __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 104
23  UIKit                           0x300ae672 -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 378
24  UIKit                           0x30121d34 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 692
25  UIKit                           0x30121804 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 156
26  UIKit                           0x300b35f0 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 456
27  UIKit                           0x300b0db4 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 300
28  UIKit                           0x3011aa2c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 56
29  UIKit                           0x301176c0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1816
30  UIKit                           0x30111ca4 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 716
31  UIKit                           0x300adc72 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3546
32  UIKit                           0x300acdd4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
33  UIKit                           0x301113e0 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 612
34  GraphicsServices                0x3271ab50 _PurpleEventCallback + 604
35  GraphicsServices                0x3271a73a PurpleEventCallback + 30
36  CoreFoundation                  0x2d841802 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
37  CoreFoundation                  0x2d84179e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
38  CoreFoundation                  0x2d83ff6a __CFRunLoopRun + 1402
39  CoreFoundation                  0x2d7aa724 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
40  CoreFoundation                  0x2d7aa506 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
41  UIKit                           0x30110606 -[UIApplication _run] + 758
42  UIKit                           0x3010b86c UIApplicationMain + 1132
43  MyAppName                       0x00017a98 main (main.m:37)
44  libdyld.dylib                   0x3850fab2 tlv_initializer + 2
```

My viewDidLoad method looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Ask for My Location data after the map has already been added to the UI.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    });

    // Listen to the myLocation property of GMSMapView.
    [self.mapView addObserver:self
                   forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
                      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                      context:NULL];


    self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;

    self.mapView.accessibilityElementsHidden = NO;
    self.mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
    self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    //Enter camera settings here
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:self.mapView.myLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:self.mapView.myLocation.coordinate.longitude zoom:14];

    self.mapView.camera = camera;
}
```

Comment: Please check the location coordinates, sometimes this type of crash used to occur when its nil.

Comment: Sounds to me like you didn't remember to type in the custom class name in your storyboard, and it's just left as NSObject.

Comment: I did add the custom class name GMSMapView. The moment I am setting a GMSMapView property in viewDidLoad:, the app crashes when uploaded through iTunes, however it continues to work perfectly in the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you have -ObjC in your debug build but not in your release build?

Comment: oh I forgot this. Works after adding the -ObjC in the distribution and release builds in "Other Linker Flags". appreciate this, thank you.